# Does $\max[E\cap F_i:E\cap F_{i-1}]\le\max[F_i:F_{i-1}]$ hold for $F_0\subset F_1\subset\cdots\subset F_n$ and $F_0\subset E\subset F_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $F_0\subset F_1\subset\cdots\subset F_n$ be a series of finite extension of fields. Suppose that $E$ is an intermediate field of $F_n/F_0$, do we necessarily have
$$
\max_{1\le i\le n}[E\cap F_i:E\cap F_{i-1}]\le\max_{1\le i\le n}[F_i:F_{i-1}]?\tag{*}
$$
Note that $[E\cap F_i:E\cap F_{i-1}]\le\max_{1\le i\le n}[F_i:F_{i-1}]$ for every $1\le i\le n$ does not need to hold, as shown by [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1483899): Let $\alpha$ satisfy an irreducible cubic $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$; let $\alpha'$ be another root of $f$. Suppose that $F_0=\mathbb{Q}$, $F_1=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $F_2=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\alpha')$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha')$, then $[F_1:F_0]=3$, $[F_2:F_1]=2$, $[E\cap F_1:E\cap F_0]=2$, $[E\cap F_2:E\cap F_1]=3$. Also, in the case where $[F_i:F_{i-1}]=2$ for all $i$, $F_n$ is called an *iterated quadratic extension* of $F_0$, so $(*)$ would imply that a subextension of an iterated quadratic extension is again an iterated quadratic extension.

Can anything be said with regard to $(*)$? Thank you for any help.

Comment: @user297024 But $E$ does not seem to be an intermediate field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8,\sqrt[8]{3})/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @user297024 Thanks a lot! You can post the comment as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @user297024 OK, thanks for your contribution!